# Light sensor on Nexus One returns only two distinct values

Tags: android, nexus-one

I´m trying to read the values of the Light Sensor of my Nexus One, but I´mgetting only following values:

10.0

225.0

and in a few cases some values much higher.

The used code:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

        listener = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                 Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Brightness: " + event.values[0]);

            }

        };
        sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }
```

Does anybody have experience with the light sensor on the Nexus One or another Android device?
Is my code the correct way to read the values?
How can I get better and more accurate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I was receiving values like this: 10, 225, 320, 640, 1280, 2600, 3200, 10240.  But I really needed to point device towards sun to receive higher values.

Edit: from light sensor characteristic that can be obtained on my phone by using Android API - 10240 is the highest value that can be returned by this sensor.

Comment: you´re right. the thing is, i obviously just tested my app on cloudy days or in the evening. Our eyes work logarithmical, whereas the device does not.